# ListView Custom Adapter - Add Video Duration

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented a videoview with 2 videos so far, I am able to set all the other textviews from database (title, user who uploaded, number of views etc) but I can not set the duration because I am only calculating this after getting my video URLs from the database, however after getting my video duration, one of 2 things happen:

- 1) The duration only updates the last textview item in the list
- 2) I get an IndexOutOfBoundException when I move my setText out of the get duration method.

My code below:

```
            @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder_video holder;

            View row=convertView;
            if(row==null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_video_single, parent, false);      
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder_video();                
            holder.ibProfilePicture = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ibProfilePicture);

            TextView tvID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
            VideoView vv = (VideoView) row.findViewById(R.id.vv);
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDuration = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
            TextView tvUser = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
            TextView tvViews = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvViews);
            tvDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            ImageButton ibProfilePicture = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ibProfilePicture);

            tvID.setText(arrID.get(position));

            //VideoView URL
            vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(arrVideoURL.get(position)));
            vv.seekTo(5000);  
            vv.pause();

            //VideoView Duration
            vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    //get video duration
                    int duration=mp.getDuration()/1000;
                    int hours = duration / 3600; 
                    int minutes = (duration / 60) - (hours * 60);
                    int seconds = duration - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) ;

                    video_length = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

                    if (hours == 0)
                    {
                        video_length = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds); 
                    }

                    System.out.println("0--> video_length: "+video_length + " "+position); // I get my TWO video durations as position 0 and position 1
                    arrDuration.add(video_length); // I add my durations to an array (List<String> arrDuration)

                    tvDuration.setText(arrDuration.get(position)); // <-- setting the text here only sets the duration to the last item only
                }
            });


            //tvDuration.setText(arrDuration.get(position));    // <-- setting the text here returns error: IndexOutOgBoundException

            tvTitle.setText(arrTitle.get(position));
            tvUser.setText(arrUser.get(position));
            tvViews.setText(arrViews.get(position));
            tvDate.setText(arrDate.get(position));

            Picasso.with(context).load(arrProfilePicture.get(position)).resize(250, 250)
            .transform(new CircleTransform()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.error).into(ibProfilePicture);   

            holder.ibProfilePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "go to user profile: "+arrUser.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             });

            return row;
        }
```

Please note the 2 `tvDuration.setText(arrDuration.get(position))` when I use either one of them, none work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are use `VideoView` it call `MediaPlayer`, in your code it providing last item in adapter with `VideoView` that’s why you got an `IndexOutOfBoundException`, because onPrepare callback get the last item `(position == lastIndex)`  and 
when you add duration to your collection `arrDuration.add(video_length)` it will be added to first position.

Check this tutorial step-by-step https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429

Comment: but I am doing arrDuration.add(video_length); so why doesn't my listview adapter get my items from the arrDuration array then?

Comment: @user3560827 because how I said onPrepared will called only by last view and after add your `arrDuration.size()=1` but position == n. Check your adapter with only one item it will be work exactly. I advise you to use HashMap<Integer,String> instead of List<String>.  Then your code will be that:\n `arrDuration.put(position,video_length); tvDuration.setText(arrDuration.get(position));`